# Is it necessary to put nameserver 1 in the first field?

Tags: dns, hosting, nameservers

Is it necessary to put the nameserver 1 in the first field in domain registrar account and name server 2 in the second field?

I mean if for example hosting company is providing these name servers.

NameServer 1:
ns.inmotionhosting.com

NameServer 2:
ns2.inmotionhosting.com

But in the domain registrar dashboard where i have to put these name servers if i exchange those name servers ( add ns1 in the field of ns2 and ns2 in field of ns1)
 For exmaple i enter:

NameServer 1:
ns2.inmotionhosting.com

NameServer 2: 
ns.inmotionhosting.com

**So is it wrong? Or it does'nt matter which name server you put in the first field and which you put in second field?**
Need correct Answer

Comment: "Need correct Answer" I think that is not needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RFC1033](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1033), the order does not matter:

> The domain system does not guarantee to preserve the order of resource
> records.  Listing RRs (such as multiple address records) in a certain
> order does not guarantee they will be used in that order.

Comment: Perfect Dusan. Thanks and  Im accepting this answer